# soft key opens only after double tapping

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have an android EditText control.

but its behavior is not as I desire.

1) only after double tapping the soft keyboard is opened.

2) when the view opens, the selection cursor is already in the editText. I wish it would appear only after the user taps.

I have tried `clearFocus()` and `setSelected(false)` but none of them helped.

Comment: Are you using custom EditText or native?

Comment: Could you post the xml you are using for EditText so I can try to reproduce the issue with the double tap problem.

Comment: can it be default settings in adnroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the xml attribute

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

or the java function

```
setCursorVisible(false).
```

As for the first part of your question:

1) only after double tapping the soft keyboard is opened.

Is this a problem with a matching question or a statement? (Post in comments)

Comment: but `setCursorVisible(false).` will make i appear after the user taps?

Comment: What are you trying to do, I guess I am not fully understanding your question. Do you not want the cursor to appear?

Comment: I think he wants the cursor visible after user taps, not when EditText gets created